# Does this mean the cursor was left open by Google's code?

Tags: android

I've trying to figure out who is leaving opened cursors so I went ahead and put my app on strict mode and it crashes fairly quickly with the stacktrace below. Does that stacktrace tell me that the cursor was left open by some of Google's code? How do I figure out which piece of code?

Thanks.

```
android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: 
Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
at 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.<init>(SQLiteCursor.java:98)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:50)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatv.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzatv.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaul.zzc(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj.zzb(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzauj$8.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaud$zzd.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently **yes**.

Came across this as well...

[See this thread](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/176#issuecomment-293641341) or check the android bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will keep an eye on that and once it updates I'll have to enable it again to see if I have another place where this is going on.